# Unexpected token "“" (0x201C)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the error I get in command prompt when running

```
    npm install discord.io winston -save"
    npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\FloppaBot/package.json
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "“" (0x201C) in JSON at position 3 while parsing near "{\r\n“name”:“Floppabot”,\r..."
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

This is my code/doc with the info for package.json

```
{
“name”: “Floppabot",
“version”: “1.0.0”,
“description”: “Feel so clean like a Zabloing Machine”,
“main”: “bot.js”,
“author”: “7xvn”,
“dependencies”: {1}
}
```

Please help me fix this error.

Comment: You have smart quotes, instead of plain quotes `"`

Comment: Also `"dependencies": {1}` is not valid - you need key-value pair(s) within `{}`

Comment: tysm vlaz! This was just what i needed actually!